# What is the best way to carry retention on a large table with 1.5bn+ records ? (SAP HANA SP12)

Tags: hana

We've a table with record count : 1,935,548,425.

We want to carry a retention activity on the same : Which keeps only the current month + last 6 months records in the table.

We're thinking of :
Partitioning the table and then dropping the older partitions (older than 6 months).

Concerns:

My concern is will partitioning the table result in any performance deterioration?
Or can anyone suggest a better mechanism to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not the partitioning approach will lead to negative performance effects depends on the kind of workload you run against the table.
If queries and data changes are usually confined to a single unit of partitioning, in your case one month, then I would not expect negative effects as still only one table-structure is processed for the queries.

However, if e.g. many joins are performed during the partitioned table and partition pruning cannot be performed before the join, then instead of a `one table:one table` join a `every partition:one table` join needs to be done, which leads to more computational work.

Considering that the main objective is data aging it might be worthwhile to look into the [SAP HANA Data Lifetime Management](https://help.sap.com/viewer/p/SAP_HANA_DATA_WAREHOUSING_FOUNDATION) features. With those, you could leverage [dynamic tiering](https://help.sap.com/viewer/p/SAP_HANA_DYNAMIC_TIERING) and multi-temperature data storage in a structured approach.

All in all, I would recommend testing your workload with the partitioned table approach and to avoid reinventing the wheel and instead use the available standard tools.

Comment: the links are broken now